# matplotlib error - no module named tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I tried to use the matplotlib package via Pycharm IDE on windows 10.
when I run this code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

I know that in python 2.x it was called Tkinter, but that is not the problem - I just installed a brand new python 3.5.1.

EDIT: in addition, I also tried to import 'tkinter' and 'Tkinter' - neither of these worked (both returned the error message I mentioned).

Comment: Have you imported tkinter by `import Tkinter` or `import tkinter` ?

Comment: `ImportError: No module named '_tkinter', please install the python3-tk package`?

Comment: @knh170 no, simply the message shown in my original post.

Comment: If you open a terminal, launch python and type `import tkinter` (if you are using python 3), it doesnt work either?

Comment: as I mentioned before - no :(

Comment: looks like you used custom installation .Rerun the python installer , press modify and then tick td/tk and IDLE

Comment: If you're using Python3.7+ and coming to this question, note that you might need to install python3.X-tk rather than just python3-tk (see Pedro's answer)

Answer (score 254, accepted):

#### For Linux

Debian based distros:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

RPM based distros:

```
sudo yum install python3-tkinter
```

#### For windows:

For Windows, I think the problem is you didn't install complete Python package. Since Tkinter should be shipped with Python out of box. See: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html . Good python distributions for Windows can be found by the companies Anaconda or ActiveState.

#### Test the python module

```
python -c "import tkinter"
```

p.s. I suggest installing [ipython](https://ipython.org/), which provides powerful shell and necessary packages as well.

Comment: IT IS WORKING! thanks! (I installed anaconda through the link you put in your post)

Comment: if you're on a CentOS box, the command is `sudo yum install python36u-tkinter.x86_64`

Comment: I am using pycharm and i got the same error regarding package missing. 
After installing tkinter package matplotlib worked fine. Thank you @knh170

Comment: Worked for me with Ubuntu 18.04 using python3 in venv. Just install it: sudo apt-get install python3-tk
Then you can test is from python3 shell: from matplotlib import pyplot

Comment: @knh170 Can we install tkinter using pip? I cannot search anything related to this

Comment: Install Ubuntu package `python3-tk` for Python3: `apt update; apt install python3-tk` (change to `python-tk` for Python2)

Comment: For newer Python versions, installing specifically `python3.7-tk`, for example, might be necessary.

Comment: Or apt-get install python3.5-tk for python 3.5

Answer (score 119):

you can use

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

if you dont want to use `tkinter` at all.

Also dont forget to use `%matplotlib inline` at the top of your notebook if using one.

EDIT: `agg` is a different backend like `tkinter` for matplotlib.

Comment: This is nice, because due to working with a server I don't require and have X11, but some programs I have installed have a dependency on matplotlib.

Comment: Fantastic! In case anyone is wondering [how this works](https://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#generate-images-without-having-a-window-appear)

Comment: In my case plots came broken after applying this solution so I run recommended `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` and all get fine

Comment: This solution is for and I quote `if you dont want to use tkinter at all.`

Comment: this solution does'nt work if you want to plot something

Comment: Just to add to this answer: `agg` is a non-GUI backend, so `plt.show()` will not have any effect. But you can still do `plt.savefig(filename)` and look at the file for quick debugging.

Comment: Saves me time from dealing with this tkinter error.

Answer (score 46):

For **Windows** users, there's no need to download the installer again. Just do the following:

1. Go to start menu, type **Apps & features**,
2. Search for "python" in the search box,
3. Select the Python version (e.g. **Python 3.8.3rc1(32-bit)**) and click **Modify**,
4. On the Modify Setup page click **Modify**,
5. Tick **td/tk and IDLE** checkbox (which installs tkinter) and click **next**.

Wait for installation and you're done.

Comment: Thank you. It is the most useful and correct answer among others.
(For Windows OS users of course)

Answer (score 36):

On Centos, the package names and commands are different. You'll need to do:

```
sudo yum install tkinter
```

To fix the problem.

Answer (score 21):

Almost all answers I searched for this issue say that Python on Windows comes with tkinter and tcl already installed, and I had no luck trying to download or install them using pip, or actviestate.com site. I eventually found that when I was installing python using the binary installer, I had unchecked the module related to TCL and tkinter. So, I ran the binary installer again and chose to modify my python version by this time selecting this option. No need to do anything manually then. If you go to your python terminal, then the following commands should show you version of tkinter installed with your Python:

```
import tkinter
import _tkinter
tkinter._test()
```

Comment: Correct. A Windows install is the only system where this can happen - as was the case for myself. +1. This is certainly worth noting for users with Windows installs.

Answer (score 19):

If you are using fedora then first install tkinter

```
sudo dnf install python3-tkinter
```

I don't think you need to import tkinter afterwards
I also suggest you to use virtualenv

```
$ python3 -m venv myvenv
$ source myvenv/bin/activate
```

And add the necessary packages using pip

Answer (score 10):

On CentOS 7 and Python 3.4, the command is `sudo yum install python34-tkinter`

On Redhat 7.4 with Python 3.6, the command is `sudo yum install rh-python36-python-tkinter`

Comment: On Centos 7 and Python 3.6, the command is `sudo yum install python36u-tkinter.x86_64`

Answer (score 8):

For windows users, re-run the installer. Select Modify. Check the box for tcl/tk and IDLE. The description for this says "Installs tkinter"

Answer (score 8):

On Ubuntu, early 2018, there is no `python3.6-tk` on ubuntu's (xenial/16.04) normal distributions, so even if you have earlier versions of `python-tk` this won't work.

My solution was to use set everything up with `python 3.5`:

```
 sudo apt install python3.5-tk
 virtualenv --python=`which python3.5` python-env
 source python-env/bin/activate
 pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And now `matplotlib` can find `tkinter`.

**EDIT**:

I just needed 3.6 afterall, and the trick was to:

```
sudo apt install tk-dev
```

and then rebuild python3.6, *after* `tk-dev`, eg:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: Update: Now there __IS__ a `python3.6-tk`! `sudo apt install python3.6-tk` works here :)

Answer (score 5):

For the poor guys like me using **python 3.7**. You need the `python3.7-tk` package.

`sudo apt install python3.7-tk`

```sh
$ python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Sep  2 2019, 20:44:09)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
>>> exit()
```

*Note. `python3-tk` is installed. But not `python3.7-tk`.*

```sh
$ sudo apt install python3.7-tk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  tix python3.7-tk-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3.7-tk
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 34 not upgraded.
Need to get 143 kB of archives.
After this operation, 534 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python3.7-tk amd64 3.7.4-1+xenial2 [143
kB]
Fetched 143 kB in 0s (364 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package python3.7-tk:amd64.
(Reading database ... 256375 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3.7-tk_3.7.4-1+xenial2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.7-tk:amd64 (3.7.4-1+xenial2) ...
Setting up python3.7-tk:amd64 (3.7.4-1+xenial2) ...
```

After installing it, all good.

```sh
$ python3
Python 3.7.4 (default, Sep  2 2019, 20:44:09)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
>>> exit()
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using python 3.6, this worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-tk
```

instead of

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Which works for other versions of python3

Comment: I don't have a python3.6-tk package on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @brooks, same here

Comment: Also did not exist on Centos

Comment: It's should be available now on ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2):

On CentOS 6.5 with python 2.7 I needed to do: `yum install python27-tkinter`

Comment: I am getting "No package python27-tkinter available."

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes (for example in osgeo4w distribution) tkinter is removed.

Try changing matplotlib backend editing *matplotlibrc* file located in `[python install dir]/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc` changing The *backend* parameter from `backend: TkAgg` to something other like `backend: Qt4Agg`as described here: http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm using Python 3.7 on Ubuntu I had to use:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7-tk
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you installed python from source. In this case, you can recompile python with tcl/tk supported.

1. Complie and install tcl/tk from http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html, I'll suppose you installed python at `/home/xxx/local/tcl-tk/`.

```
# install tcl
wget -c https://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/tcl/tcl8.6.9-src.tar.gz
tar -xvzf tcl8.6.9-src.tar.gz
cd tcl8.6.9
./configure --prefix=/home/xxx/local/tcl-tk/
make
make install

# install tk
wget -c https://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/tcl/tk8.6.9.1-src.tar.gz
tar -xvzf tk8.6.9.1-src.tar.gz
cd tk8.6.9.1
./configure --prefix=/home/xxx/local/tcl-tk/
make
make install
```

2. Recompile python with tcl/tk supported, for example:

```
# download the source code of python and decompress it first.

cd <your-python-src-dir>
./configure --prefix=/home/xxx/local/python \
 --with-tcltk-includes=/home/xxx/local/tcl-tk/include \
 --with-tcltk-libs=/home/xxx/local/tcl-tk/lib
make 
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Win x86/64 because my custom Python3.7 installation did not include Tcl packages, so just modify or re-install your python

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Download Python Setup file and click modify then tick the tcl/tk and install.

After installation is complete go to folder where python is installed ( Default is C:\Users**Your username**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib) .

Copy the tkinter folder and paste it in the lib folder of your pycharm project.

Error should be resolved

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps to easily install Tkinter on your PyCharm IDE:**

First go to the File:
[image]

Second is go to New Project Setup > Settings for new projects:
[image]

And then click the Settings for new projects and you'll get redirected in here:
[image: Please make sure to select the Python Interpreter]

Please click the + symbol in there:
[image]

after that install future and there you go...
[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you’re having pip(which you probably do), open up cmd or powershell on Windows or a terminal window on OS X or Linux and try this(make sure python is in the system path if you’re on Windows):

```
pip install tkinter
```

It should take a while to install tkinter, and then try to execute this code block:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
# Your code goes here 
root.mainloop()
```

Hope that this helps! Thank you!