# No matching distribution found for tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, module, tk-toolkit

I am stuck with this issue since last two days and I have tried every possible solution on the stack and github. It will be really great if someone can recommend.

I am working with python 2.7 in a virtual environment on CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611.

I am running a script that uses matplotlib.pyplot and on run gives this error

```
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 File "/usr/local/packages/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named _tkinter
```

I tried to install tkinter using -

```
 pip install tkinter and it gave this error 
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tkinter
```

then I even installed -

```
sudo yum install tk
sudo yum install tk-devel
sudo yum install tc
```

and it says packages are already installed and `nothing to to`

I have set up my virtual environment again to see if I missed something but I cannot get anywhere. Please help!

Comment: on the newest Ubuntu I had to install `python-tkinter` using `apt-get` (similar to `yum`). `tk` and `tcl` are used by `tkinter` but they don't install `tkinter` in `python`

Comment: maybe check if `yum` has command `search/find` and try to find `tkinter` (not `tk`)

Comment: @furas , yes I read it in multiple forums, but when I try to install `tk` and `tcl` it tells me there is nothing to do!

Comment: it gives me `tk-8.5.13-6.el7.x86_64` is already installed and on yum search for tkinter it returns - `python2-tktable.x86_64 : TkTable wrapper for Python 2.x with Tkinter
python34-tkinter.x86_64 : A GUI toolkit for Python 3
tkinter.x86_64 : A graphical user interface for the Python scripting language`

Comment: `tk/tcl` is not `tkinter`. `tkinter` is wrapper which needs language `tk/tcl` to work but `tk/tcl` doesn't need `tkinter` to run (so it doesn't add `tkinter` to `Python`)

Comment: maybe you have to install  `python34-tkinter` but it seems it is for Python 3.4

Comment: Try `sudo yum reinstall tkinter`.

Comment: Tray `import Tkinter` instead of `import tkinter` in python 2.7

Answer (score 42):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

this worked for me

Comment: I needed sudo apt-get install python3.6-tk

Comment: Why can't this module be included with pip?

Comment: @yamanidev because it is **not a Python package**. It will reconfigure the system so as to ensure that Tcl/Tk (which is pure C code that can be used in other contexts) is installed and accessible from Python, *in addition to* installing the `_tkinter` module in the right place. Also, because it modifies the system Python, where **Pip may have been deliberately disabled**.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `apt-get install python-tk`

Answer (score 1):

had same issue: `yum install tkinter` for CentOS and RedHat for python 2.x!

Answer (score 1):

For people still experiencing this issue, try to change your Python project interpreter. Tkinter should be included by default, but it is possible that your distribution does not have it included. Always download the latest base interpreter from the official site.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error as you, I try installing dependencies, tk/tcl, but it didn't work. Finally I solved it using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

on ubuntu16.04

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo yum install python-tools -y
```

This worked for me on Amazon Linux 2.

Answer (score -2):

Since you are using python 2.7 tkinter is Tkinter. Try importing Tkinter.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html

Comment: so if I got to python prompt and use import Tkinter, i get File `"/usr/local/packages/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named _tkinter`

Comment: also the path for python in my virtual env is `/home//CVD_venv/lib/python2.7/`  not `/usr/local/packages/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/`  so python still looks for this module in the root/central location?

Comment: You probably tried this but on this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36327134/matplotlib-error-no-module-named-tkinter

Comment: "On CentOS 6.5 with python 2.7 I needed to do: yum install python27-tkinter"

Comment: Yes I did try this earlier - it gives me this message `No package python27-tkinter available.
Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: i did `sudo apt-get install  python27-tkinter` but i get `E: Unable to locate package python27-tkinter` mybe you must instal it in python3 by this  `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` i did it and worked. in python 2.7 you coud use `import Tkinter`.