# Python3. Importing matplotlib.pyplot is not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've just finished an online course about python for Data Science. 
I wanted to code something by my own in Pycharm Edu. I had done this before and everything was working. I downloaded "numpy" and "matplotlib" via Pycharm and console in Linux Mint. When I import numpy and import matplotlib ( and write nothing else ) my program is running properly, but when I write
***"import matplotlib.pyplot as plt"*** it is not working.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8Lvq.png) Screen: https://snag.gy/CPx9WG.jpg

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36327134/matplotlib-error-no-module-named-tkinter

Comment: The error tells you what is wrong. You do not have tkinter installed.

Comment: Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `tkinter`

```
apt-get install python-tk
```

Docs found here: [Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter)